# Может ли список быть полем класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Допустим, есть класс, и я в нём задаю поле, как список

```
class Calculator:
    history = [[], []]
```

Однако, если затем в методе пишу такой код:

```
Calculator.history[1] = (self.a, self.b, self.act, self.c)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

объект 'function' не поддерживает назначение элемента

Но я же задал поле, а не функцию?? Как мне сделать список, который будет жить внутри класса? причем, двумерный

Comment: Покажите полное описание класса. Нет ли у вас в нём метода `history` случайно? )

Comment: А ведь реально есть такой метод, я тупой, извините. Определил метод и список с одним названием.

Comment: Не переживайте, это типичные грабли начинающих в Питоне )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде норм

```
class Calculator:
    history = [[], []]

    def __init__(self, a, b, act, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.act, self.c = a, b, act, c
        Calculator.history[1] = (self.a, self.b, self.act, self.c)


Calculator(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(Calculator.history) # [[], (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```